# How to wiki not updated in Flyver SDK

Tags: sdk, ar.drone, drone.io

I wanted to mimick video streaming, photo capture etc for android and iOS mobile apps using Drones. I have found Android support is available by Flyver here - http://flyver.co/drone-api-sdk/.

But, I could not find anything that suffice my needs as flyver wiki is not well updated.Please let me know how could I simulate Drone apps using Flyver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flyver SDK will soon support video streaming and restreaming from cameras such as GoPro.

You could run the apps on any Android phone and test without the drone. 
Download the Hello Flyver application to get you started:

https://github.com/flyver/Flyver-Apps/tree/master/HelloFlyver

For further questions you could write directly into the forum pages: http://flyver.co/forum/